# How do I use ziplines?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

I came across a zipline in Colony 4 that leads to a glowing container. How do I use the zipline?

[image]

Comment: You need a rubber chicken with a pulley in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t use the ziplines until mid-chapter 4. By doing the story related hero quest for

> [Juniper](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Juniper)

After completing this hero quest, you’ll be taught how to ride on ziplines. Once you obtain this ability, you can then backtrack to previous areas to obtain contains and unlock new areas that were previously inaccessible.